# Can I transfer iTunes credit between accounts?

Tags: apple-id, itunes-store

How would I go about transferring iTunes credit between accounts?

The question pretty well speaks for itself. I have two accounts, one for my iPod, one for my iPhone, I have passwords to both accounts, I can handle talking to Apple Support if that's what needs be, but I was curious if I can transfer the funds without going through customer service. Should I just "gift" myself purchases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This totally will not work. iTunes explicitly says gift certificate balances can not be used to purchase other gift certificates. I will call apple tomorrow to find another work around.

Answer (score 3):

You can not transfer allowance you have already redeemed onto a separate account - I am having just this problem at the moment and I am seriously pissed off with the difficulty and the lack of help ITunes give

Comment: I agree that enough people have issues with small amounts of credit. Apple could program a refund/donation mechanism whereby it offered to donate the remaining amount to a charity or two and then let users move their accounts once any store credit has been disposed. If an outright refund isn't practical, at least make it easy for people to dispose of their balances without waiting for days to get a response from a web form.

Answer (score 1):

Gifting content from one account to the other would be the simplest way to accomplish what you are looking for (albeit, this means you have to do the gifting from the device with the funds).

Comment: Yes, but there’s a $15 minimum for that, and my daughter has only earned $8…

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can use your account balance to send another user a (virtual) gift card.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [making an allowance to the desired account](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2105)? That works between $10 and $50 so you should be able to drain any amount more than $10 this way over time by making sure the last month balance is at least $10. It doesn't involve purchasing a new gift card which is explicitly not allowed and may just work.

You can gift apps for the last $10 if the balance is initially less than $10 or the math doesn't work out nicely.

You might want to remove your credit card temporarily from the sending account in case it charges the allowance instead of spending down a store credit.

Comment: I haven't set up an allowance on any accounts. This was a one-off question, that I figured had broader appeal in the long run. I wasn't able to do with it what I wanted regardless. But thanks for the Q, and I would love to know if you ever give it a go.

Comment: I'm loathe to make yet another account to test - but agree that the question in the abstract is a good one and over time should hold the authoritative answer to your question. Many others will end up in the same boat in time.

Comment: From someone in the same boat - I can confirm this is not currently possible.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, it's totally possible to call and get a credit issued as a check, if the balance was put there by a credit card or the like. This was how I ended up with such a balance, and I did not know you could do this. :D

Comment: I wonder if this is still possible in 2015?

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of transferring an iTunes balance to another account, I have used dollars on my iPad to Purchase an app on my grandson's iPod, by using my iPad apple ID on his iPod.  The problem with that is that to update the app, he has to have your iPad apple ID.  Another way is to purchase apps on the iPad, back up to my PC, then connect his iPod to my PC and Install the app on the iPod.  You still have the same problem if he wants to update the app on his iPod, he has to have my iPad apple ID and password.